# Streaming Levels Limits?

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

In UE it seems the only way to seamlessly travel between levels is with blueprint level streaming. My goal is to have a "loading level" which is a very basic, always loaded level that becomes visible when loading into a real level. Upon load completion, loading level plays an animation and then hides itself and fades into the real level.

I set up a map that I named `PersistentMap` that only has an actor `PersistentOrigin` which holds some global variables and event dispatchers. So all streamed sub-levels can use `PersistentOrigin` to send event calls (which are handled by `PersistentMap` blueprint) and use it's globals. The sub-levels in `PersistentMap` are the `LoadingMap`, `MainMenu` and various other sub-levels.

This has been working really well and smooth so far while testing, but my main concern is when I have more than 10 or so sub-levels with a lot of actors, meshes, and textures. And all being contained in `PersistentMap`.

So, I have a few questions regarding this setup, and all responses are valid and appreciated since this is very technical:

1. On the editor side while developing, if I use the option `Show Stats > Stats > Engine > Levels` for the `PersistentMap` it shows that all the sub-levels are "Loaded Not Visible". Doesn't this mean that while I have this map open in the editor, all the sub-levels are loaded in memory? Is there a way to only load them if they're visible in the editor? I feel like this will get really taxing on my (and other devs') system later in development, no?
2. After building the game and launching it, does the amount of "Unloaded" sub-levels and their content in the `PersistentLevel` affect initial load time? When I play test, the `Level Stats` show all other levels as "Unloaded" when I would want them to be. Fine and dandy. I'm only assuming this means the amount of sub-levels won't affect the initial load time?
3. Is the method of communication between levels described above through event dispatchers and some variables in a `PersistentOrigin` actor viable? It at least made my blueprints cleaner when I thought of giving that a try...

This has been something bothering me since I started developing with UE5, and can't find any in-depth or reputable sources for answers and/or work-arounds. Thank you to everyone in advance <3

Answer (score 0):

After doing tons of testing, the answer is yes, just the persistent level is loaded in memory and then the sub levels will be loaded when needed.

Comment: I'm just now noticing you made an answer! This is very helpful, but before I go ahead and implement this again, do you know if there's a way to keep the sub-levels from loading into memory in the engine itself? It seemed that when I was using this method, all the levels would be loaded when working on the project, and that would be very taxing once there's a whole bunch of levels...